# CD command in build.xml file

Tags: bash, ant

I work with ant and bash script. I want to calling bash script from ant . I have script

```
        <exec executable="echo">
           <arg value=" 1... "/>
        </exec>
```

it is works fine, but this code not

```
        <exec executable="cd ">
           <arg value="/home"/>
        </exec>
```

Why does't work "cd" command ? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd /": error=2, No such file or directory

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you cannot "execute" `cd` from ant. `cd` is not an executable. `cd` is a shell builtin.

if you are trying to change the current working directory then you can use the `dir` attribute of the [`exec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task.

see also: [Change working directory in ant junit task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366821/change-working-directory-in-ant-junit-task)